# Adding things to the emptiest list? (python)

Tags: python

I am looking for a simple way to compare the content of multiple lists and find the one with the fewest variables.

Then I want to set the new variable to be added to that list.

Example:

```
list1 = [1,5,7,12,4,8]
list2 = [3,2,9,11,14,6,10]
list3 = [13,15,16]
```

In this I would want it to find list3 to be the shortest and append the new value to it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys between you and the direction it pointed me in I got everything I needed and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to pythons `min`, `max`, and `sort`'s `key` keyword argument this is fairly simple to do in python

```
min([list1, list2, list3..], key = len).append(item)
```

key corresponds to the function applied to each element and whose result is used for comparison in both [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).  in this case the function `len` (which retrieves the length of sequence objects like list and tuple and any class that defines `__len__` ) is used.

from `min`.

> The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort()

from [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element (for example, key=str.lower).

example

```
>>> x = [11231]
>>> y = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> z = [1,2,3,4,1,1]
>>> min([x,y,z], key = len)
[11231]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write a small function that checks the `len` of each list, then `append` to that list.

```
def add_to_shortest(lists, item):
    min(lists, key = lambda i: len(i)).append(item)
```

For example

```
>>> add_to_shortest([list1, list2, list3], 5)
>>> list3
[13, 15, 16, 5]
```